# Why is the differential operator equal to an integer in the case of trignometric equations?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, differential-operators

In this website, http://www.codecogs.com/library/maths/calculus/differential/the-d-operator.php, the following problem and solution is given:

Problem:

> Find the Particular Integral of
>   $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - 5\,\frac{dy}{dx} + 6y = \sin\,2x$$

Solution:

> This can be re-written as
>   $$\tag1
> y = \frac{1}{D^2 - 5D + 6}\sin\,2x
> $$
>
> Using equation 1 we can put $D^2 = -4$
>
> Therefore:
>   $$y = \frac{1}{-\,4\;-\,5D + 6}\sin\,2x
> =\frac{1}{2 - 5D}\sin\,2x$$
>
> If we multiply the top and bottom of this equation by 2 + 5D
>
> $$y =\frac{2 + 5D}{4 - 25D^2}\sin\,2x$$
>
> But $D^2=-4$
>
> Therefore
>   $$ y =\frac{2 + 5D}{104}\sin\,2x = \frac{1}{104}\left(2\sin\,2x + 5D\sin\,2x \right)$$
>   But since $D\sin\,2x = 2\cos\,2x$
>   $$y = \frac{1}{104}\left(2\sin\,2x + 10\cos\,2x \right) $$

The biggest problem I have with this is the line, $D^2 = -4$.

So far as I understand, $D$ is an operator on functions, and $D^2$ represents the double application of that operator. So how, can it be equal to -4? How can an operator on functions be equal to an integer? They're two things of fundamentally different types, how can they be equal?

Comment: In differential equations like this, however weird and illegitimate the methods in the middle are, if you can check your solution at the end you are done.  There is no need to use legitimate deduction in the middle, or to understand why it works.

Comment: GEdgar, I understand the derivation but not why it works, and I want to find out. I don't have to know, but I want to.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: in the source, yes there is. Here, I have edited it in.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Are you talking about my question or the article? If it's my question, I'll edit it to be more professional, if you want.

Comment: What is going on in the quoted material (outlined in skintone) is black magic. Operating in this way might be allowed in a private diary, with a lot of explanations and assumptions left unwritten, but not in a text addressed to a larger public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can interpret $D^2=-4$ as $D^2=-4I$, where $I$ is the identity operator; that's no big deal. If anything, you should be more worried about "dividing" by an operator.

To expand a bit about what's going on in that solution, the author knows that the solution will be a linear combination of $\sin(2x)$ and $\cos(2x)$. **For those two functions** (and their linear combinations), $D^2=-4I$.

Note that guessing all those manipulations is harder than postulating that the particular solution is of the form $\alpha\sin(2x)+\beta\cos(2x)$ and substitute in the equation to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (what is usually known as [Undetermined Coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients)).

Comment: I would solve the equation by noting that $(D-2)(D-3)y=\sin 2x.$ Find $z$ such that  $(D-3)z=\sin 2x$   and solve  $(D -2)y=z.$..............+1

Comment: That's a much more rational approach than the one from the link above. Still, it makes you solve two first order DE as opposed to just find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as in Undetermined Coefficients. The good thing about your method is that it works in general, and it is not doing shady manipulations of the operators.

Comment: The main  "shady" part is that we have to know in advance that $y$ is a linear combination of $\cos 2x$ and $\sin 2x$  in order to know that $D^2y=-4y.$

Comment: Dividing by an operator makes kinda more sense in my head. In the group of differential operators, which is closed under addition and application, there must exist inverses, so I read $\frac{1}{D^2−5D+6} \sin 2x$ as "apply the inverse of the operator $D^2−5D+6$ to the function $\sin 2x$.

Comment: Only that you cannot really combine the inverse (as in composition) with algebra of fractions as the example does. The reason the trick works is that you don't need the "division" step: $(D^2-5D+6)y=f$ is $(2-5D)y=f $;  now apply $2+5D $ to get $104y=(2+5D)f $.